# Create a table of contents from a pdf file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-2d

I'm using quartz to display pdf content, and I need to create a table of contents to navigate through the pdf. From reading Apple's documentation I think I am supposed to use CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog, but I can't find any examples on how to use this anywhere. Any ideas?

**Update:** Still haven't found a solution for this. I tired Alex' solution but the output I get looks like this:

```
2011-07-27 09:16:19.359 LDS Scriptures App-iPad[624:707] key: Pages
2011-07-27 09:16:19.361 LDS Scriptures App-iPad[624:707] key: Count
2011-07-27 09:16:19.362 LDS Scriptures App-iPad[624:707] pdf integer value: 238
2011-07-27 09:16:19.363 LDS Scriptures App-iPad[624:707] key: Kids
2011-07-27 09:16:19.366 LDS Scriptures App-iPad[624:707] key: Type
2011-07-27 09:16:19.368 LDS Scriptures App-iPad[624:707] key: Outlines
2011-07-27 09:16:19.370 LDS Scriptures App-iPad[624:707] key: Count
2011-07-27 09:16:19.371 LDS Scriptures App-iPad[624:707] pdf integer value: 7
2011-07-27 09:16:19.372 LDS Scriptures App-iPad[624:707] key: First
2011-07-27 09:16:19.374 LDS Scriptures App-iPad[624:707] key: Parent
2011-07-27 09:16:19.375 LDS Scriptures App-iPad[624:707] key: Count
2011-07-27 09:16:19.376 LDS Scriptures App-iPad[624:707] pdf integer value: 7
```

No idea yet how to turn that into a usable table of contents. Ideally I would like to get to an array of `NSDictionary` objects with a title and matching page number.

Comment: Ryan, did you found any way to create TOC from existing PDF? If so please guide me. I m searching for the same since few days.

Comment: Have you found any solution? If yes, please add your answer here.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this might help you get started:

```
NSURL *documentURL = ...; // URL to file or http resource etc.
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)documentURL);
CGPDFDictionaryRef pdfDocDictionary = CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog(pdfDocument);
// loop through dictionary...
CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction(pdfDocDictionary, ListDictionaryObjects, NULL);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfDocument);

...

void ListDictionaryObjects (const char *key, CGPDFObjectRef object, void *info) {
    NSLog("key: %s", key);
    CGPDFObjectType type = CGPDFObjectGetType(object);
    switch (type) { 
        case kCGPDFObjectTypeDictionary: {
            CGPDFDictionaryRef objectDictionary;
            if (CGPDFObjectGetValue(object, kCGPDFObjectTypeDictionary, &objectDictionary)) {
                CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction(objectDictionary, ListDictionaryObjects, NULL);
            }
        }
        case kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger: {
            CGPDFInteger objectInteger;
            if (CGPDFObjectGetValue(object, kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger, &objectInteger)) {
                NSLog("pdf integer value: %ld", (long int)objectInteger); 
            }
        }
        // test other object type cases here
        // cf. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFObject/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001117-CH3g-SW1
    }    
}
```

Comment: Where is `CGPDFDocumentApplyFunction` defined?

Comment: Sorry, that should be `CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction`. See the `CGPDFDictionary.h` header file in the `CoreGraphics.framework`. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Hi @AlexReynolds, can you convert your answer for Swift 3 as well?

Answer (score 4):

Here is my approach.

1. Download this framework [**`vfr reader`**](https://github.com/vfr/Reader)

2. Use this lines of code to get all PDF chapters

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Reader" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSArray *arr = [ReaderDocumentOutline outlineFromFileURL:targetURL password:@""];
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me using vfr reader and this snippet. Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You create a Table of Contents (AKA Outlines, Bookmarks) using PDFKit's [PDFOutline](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfoutline) object. You can also read existing Outlines within a PDF.

`CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog` is a method for getting the Catalog of PDF data in the file, which is at a much lower-level than human concepts of 'Contents'.

In the absence of existing Outlines, I'm not sure there's a way to get meaningful data from the PDF stream itself, e.g. trying to grok Chapter headings just from the PDF data.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a freeware library for iOS [**`FastPdfKit`**](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Developer-Tools/FastPdfKit.shtml)