# Table of contents from PDF Document using CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-2d

Can anyone provide a sample code to get table of contents from PDF Document? I have googled for more than 2 days but couldn't find any proper example. I m also having **Voyuer Example** suggested from many blogs but was not able to understand it. Is there any simple way???

Answer (score 1):

looks like the closest thing seen on SO is [Create a table of contents from a pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556344/create-a-table-of-contents-from-a-pdf-file)