# How to delete PDF file's bookmarks with PDFKit in Mac?

Tags: macos, bookmarks, pdfkit

I need to  delete PDF file's bookmarks with PDFKit .

The bookmarks are within the PDF file. Not to make a mutable array to track bookmarks and sustain it.

[image]

And I did not get imformation ( powerful API ) from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html

Other related technology stack is also welcomed.

Comment: You might want to look at outline function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556344/create-a-table-of-contents-from-a-pdf-file/60248097#60248097